# Scala -- are map and filter operations in linear time?

Tags: scala, big-o

Are Scala map and filter operations in linear time, or is there some parallelism under the hood for data structures like Arrays?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no parallelism at all, unless you're doing [parallel collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html) which is kinda explicit. Even with parallelism, the map and filter are linear time operations (but spread among many workers)

Answer (score 16):

Independently of parallelism, `map` and `filter` operations always have to do at least `O(n)` work where `n` is the number of elements in the collection.
If the collection is e.g. `Array`, `List`, `ArrayBuffer`, `HashMap` or `HashSet`, then `filter` and `map` do `O(n)` work.
For specific collections like balanced trees -- e.g. `mutable.TreeSet`, `immutable.TreeMap`, `immutable.HashSet` or `immutable.Vector`, the `filter` and `map` take `O(n logn)` time, because updating them to add all the elements takes more and more work as the collection grows.

Independently of how much work is needed to traverse all the elements, many Scala collections (typically those based on trees, maps, tries and arrays) support parallel `filter` and `map`, so the total amount of work done per processor is `O(n / p)`, where `p` is the number of processors your machine has. To use them call `par` on the collection before calling `filter` or `map`.

Read more about [parallel collections here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html).

Comment: I like all the content in your answer, but am going to accept the other one, as its conciseness works nicely with my use of StackOverflow.  I'm upvoting yours, however.

Comment: I'd quibble with the statement in the 2nd paragraph that "the total amount of work done is `O(n / p)`." That is not correct. The total amount of work is still `O(n)`. However, the time to completion is `O(n / p)`. Of course, it's really `Ω(n / p)`, since the conceptual independence of the computations carried out concurrently are in fact interfering with each other by their use of shared cache and RAM.

Comment: I've edited the "total work" part, your're right. About the interference, of course, this is a theoretical model that does not reflect some of the specifics of the particular hardware.

Comment: @flavian mapping inside a blocking future is thread safe if the mapping itself is safe, i.e. it does not access shared state concurrently that could result in data races or data corruption.